# BizTalk JSON Receive Pipeline Decoder - Does it have to add a root wrapper element?

Tags: json, biztalk, pipeline

The BizTalk decoder pipeline component displays values of RootNode and RootNodeNamespace in the configuration of the pipeline (in BizTalk Admin Console).

When I don't specify the root, it blows up and says:
"Reason: Root node name is not specifed in Json decoder properties"

When I do specify a root, it gets added. But why does it need to add a root if I have a "root" in my JSON?

Example JSON:

```
 { "AppRequest": { 
       "DocumentName": "whatever", 
       "Source": "whatever" 
       }
   }
```

So I would like to use the JSON above, and have a schema with a root of "AppRequest".  But if I drop a file with this JSON, and specify AppRequest as the Root, then I get an extra AppRequest wrapper around the AppRequest I already have.

To me this is odd behavior, if you want to have a schema/contract first approach.  I might agree on the JSON with my trading partner, then later build the schema in BizTalk; and now I'm locked in to a schema with a root, and an element under it with the same name again.

Further, the person building the JSON is probably deserializing a class, so the class name will be the "root" of that JSON file.

Yes, I could write my own decoder pipeline components ... just trying to figure out why they did it the way they did it, or if I missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a root node and namespace is required by the JSON Decoder.

*There is a reason for this.*  JSON does not require the equivalent of a root node while XML does require a root node.  Making it a required property **eliminates any ambiguity** about the conversion.  It's just that simple.

Since you will typically need to use the **XML Disassembler** also, you can strip the JSON Encoder added rood node by essentially **Debatching the content with an Envelope Schema** matching the JSON Encoder root node.  You can **remove the Xml Namespace** as well which is also a good idea.

Comment: Is there any example how to do that?

Comment: Sure, any example of BizTalk Debatching Xml will work.  Nothing special about this scenario.